# Getting FileNotFoundException while querying individual column from HIVE table for S3 data

Tags: hive

I have created a table in HIVE by using below statement. My input data is located in `S3(s3n://test/hiveTest/01/)`.

```
CREATE external TABLE tests3(firstName STRING, lastName STRING) ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location 's3n://test/hiveTest/01/';
```

I can see result data when i issue below command .

> hive> select * from tests3; OK first   second third   fourth Time
>   taken: 1.647 seconds

But when i do select specific column from a table gives below error

> hive> select firstName from tests3; Total MapReduce jobs = 1 Launching
>   Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no
>   reduce operator java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   /tests3/hiveTest/01/abc.txt
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:736)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat$OneFileInfo.(CombineFileInputFormat.java:462)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getMoreSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:256)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:387)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:353)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:387)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:989)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:981)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:891)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:844)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:844)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:818)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:452)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:136)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:133)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1332)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1123)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:931)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:255)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:671)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:554)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208) Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File
>   does not exist: /test/hiveTest/01/abc.txt)' FAILED: Execution Error,
>   return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pleas try to set bellow parameter before query run:

```
SET hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Wawrzyniec. Its working fine after setting the above attribute.